# Batch file If statement cmd

Tags: cmd

I am trying to make a batch file where user inputs a letter and then there would be message
that displayed that drive letter is or isn't available . If the letter is available then it would substitute  c:\users..... I am new to this so any help would be great. This is what I have which is incorrect

```
@echo off





if  [%1] == [c]GOTO MESS
if [%1]== [d]  GOTO MESS

If NOT [%1]==[c] GOTO LABEL
If not [%1]==[d} GOTO LABEL
:LABEL
echo this drive letter is available
pause
subst %1: "c:\users\mydocuments"
echo Successful

:MESS
echo The drive letter you entered is in use 

:END
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what question are you asking.

Answer (score 0):

After calling the `subst` command, you can check the %errorlevel% variable. Most commands set this variable to 0 if they succeeded and to something other than 0 to signal problems.

```
subst %1: "c:\users\mydocuments"
if NOT [%errorlevel%]==[0] GOTO MESS
```

There is no need for the GOTO LABEL lines. Your checks with GOTO MESS are enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
if exist %1:\ (
     echo Drive %1: is in already in use
  ) else (
     subst %1: "c:\users\mydocuments"
     echo Successful
)
```